# Prove $A$ is a diagonalisable matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

> Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ such that $\det(A)<0$. Show that $A$ is diagonalisable.

Setting

$$A=
\begin{pmatrix} 
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{pmatrix}$$

We get $p_A(\lambda)=\lambda^2-(a+d)\lambda+ad-bc$. How can I conclude that  $A$ is diagonalisable?

Comment: Is it $n\times n$ or $2\times 2$. To answer your question where is $\det(A)$ in $p_A(\lambda)$?

Comment: So "$n$" is a placeholder for "$2$"?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, then $\alpha\beta=\det A<0$. Therefore, $\alpha\neq\beta$.

Comment: So I have two distinct eigenvalues  and therefore  diagonalisable

Comment: @newhere Indeed.

Comment: Shouldn’t we first asssure ourselves that neither $\alpha$ nor $\beta$ are complex numbers?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe If they are complex, then they are conjugate. Therefore, $\alpha\beta=\alpha\overline\alpha=|\alpha|^2\geqslant0$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Of course I’m aware of that fact, but is has to be mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Distinct eigenvalues implies diagonalizable. 
Note that, $detA$=Product of eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $ad-bc$ is negative. Now
Descartes rule of signs guarantees that $x^2+px+q=0$ has a positive and a negative real solution, provided that $q$ is negative.